# why I'm receiving corrupted url parameters when I'm sending them via email

Tags: url

I'm trying to send parameter in an email within an a tag and the value of the parameter is being converted to %5E����ɒ�%7D������Cўa0%20�%7DzM
also this time the value was GFRDSGGGGGHHHHBBBBAD%23%40EDGSJD%26%5E%25

"myweb.com"

the value to the database is OK but the value which I'm sending via email being corrupted

Like for an explanation

Comment: Are you asking why the sent text is being "corrupted" in the sent email?